# Laravel. Change url for nicer link

Tags: php, laravel

Wants to change my link to a better one, for example:

This url `Route::get('/sections/{id}','SectionController@show');` gives me adress `laravel.dev/sections/1`. How i can change `/1` to `laravel.dev/sections/section_name` without htaccess. Is It possible?
Thx for help.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/sections/{section}','SectionController@show');
```

**Controller**

```
 public function show(Section $section)
{
    $listSections = $section->user;
    return view('sections.section', compact('listSections'));
}
```

**View**

```
<a href="{{URL::to('/sections/'.$listSection->name)}}">{{$section->name}}</a>
```

Comment: just change route and pass section_name instead of id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the route and access the route with section name instead. You might have to change your controller depending on how you retrieve the model.  If you are using implicit route model binding, add the following to your Section eloquent model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'section_name';
}
```

If you are explicitly fetching it, you might have to make the corresponding changes as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this but its not good practice.

```
 if(window.location.href.indexOf("/sections/") > -1) {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, '/sections/your_section_name');
  }
```